# Existem métodos estáticos em Python?

Tags: python, métodos-estáticos

Existem métodos estáticos em Python? Se existem como faço para fazer um método estático?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use o decorador `@staticmethod`:

```
class Classe(object):
    @staticmethod
    def funcao(arg1, arg2):
        pass
```

esse código produz:

```
class Classe():
    def funcao(arg1, arg2):
        pass

funcao = staticmethod(funcao)
```

pode chamar seu método assim:

```
Classe.funcao(arg1, arg2)
```

Veja mais sobre a função built-in `staticmethod(function)` na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod). E o [código fonte](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/funcobject.c#l748) - em C.

Se não quiser utilizar o decorador, [outra forma de conseguir isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25041766/6241184) é declarando a função fora da classe. Supondo que você tenha o `cachorro.py`:

```
class Cachorro(object):
    def __init__(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome

    def latir(self):
        if nome = "Ted":
            return som_de_latido()
        else:
            return "woof woof!"

def som_de_latido():
    return "au au!"
```

No código acima a função `som_de_latido()` **faz papel de uma função estática**. Pode chamá-lo como `cachorro.som_de_latido()`. É diferente do decorador pois lá você chama como `arquivo.Classe.funcao()` e aqui é `arquivo.funcao()`.

Ao optar por fazer fora da classe você não está criando um método estático de verdade, somente conseguindo uma implementação semelhante. Citei só porque é possível.

Comment: No caso seria `Cachorro.som_de_latido()` ou `cachorro.som_de_latido()`, mesmo ?

Comment: Em quais dos casos? Com o decorador?

Comment: Você diz: " Pode chamá-lo como `cachorro.som_de_latido()` ", pode ser assim mesmo ou deveria ser `Cachorro.som_de_latido()`?

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, com `staticmethod`, utilize `Classe.funcao()` (`Cachorro.som_de_latido()`). No segundo exemplo, definindo a função fora da classe, utilize `arquivo.funcao()` (`cachorro.som_de_latido()`)

Comment: hum, era isso que eu num tava entendendo, não que eu tenha entendido, mas já clareou

Comment: Obrigado amigo, me ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 7):

Usando o [@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class Exemplo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def soma(x,y):
        return x+y
    def subtrai(x,y):
        return x-y

print(Exemplo.soma(2,2));
```